# Can't change Boolean array values with forEach in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, foreach, boolean

I realized that when I try to change the values of a boolean array with `forEach` or `map` functions, the values don't change. I have to construct a for loop and change elements by index. I want to know why is this so?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a flawed understanding of how `forEach()` and `map()` work.

#### [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

`forEach()` invokes the callback method for every element in the array, but does in itself not change the array. To actually change the array using `forEach()`, you would have to use the index in your callback function:

```js
const array = [true, true];

array.forEach((v, i, a) => a[i] = !v);

console.log(array); // [false, false]
```

#### [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Similar to `forEach()`, `map()` does not change the array it is called on. It applies the callback function on every element in the array, and returns a *new* array containing the transformed elements. This means that you have to assign the result of the `map()` operation back to a variable:

```js
const array = [true, true];

const result = array.map(v => !v);

console.log(result); // [false, false]
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. I remember changing array elements for other types of objects. Is this related to the mutability?

Comment: Yes. You can change the properties of objects in an array, but if you would want to replace them with a new object, you'd have to use the above approach.